# Amazon S3 Client NOT listing all folders in the bucket

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list all so-called `folders` and `sub-folders` in an `s3` bucket.
Now, as I am trying to list all the folders in a path recursively I am not using `withDelimeter()` function.
All the so-called `folder` names should end with `/` and this is my logic to list all the folders and sub-folders.

Here's the `scala` code (Intentionally not pasting the `catch` code here):

```
val awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsKey, awsSecretKey)
val client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials)
def listFoldersRecursively(bucketName: String, fullPath: String): List[String] = {
  try {
    val objects = client.listObjects(bucketName).getObjectSummaries
    val listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
      .withPrefix(fullPath)
      .withBucketName(bucketName)
    val folderPaths = client
      .listObjects(listObjectsRequest)
      .getObjectSummaries()
      .map(_.getKey)
    folderPaths.filter(_.endsWith("/")).toList
  }
}
```

[Here's the structure of my `bucket` through an `s3 client`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33BUE.png)

[Here's the list I am getting using this `scala` code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DS4C.png)

Without any apparent pattern, many folders are missing from the list of retrieved folders. 
I did not use

```
client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest).getCommonPrefixes.toList
```

because it was returning empty list for some reason.

**P.S: Couldn't add photos in post directly because of being a new user.**

Comment: You can have a look at [Benji](https://github.com/zengularity/benji) for an easy S3/Scala integration.

Comment: The functions for `listFiles`, `listFilesRecusively` and `listFolders` are working just fine. It's not feasible to switch for me at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Without any apparent pattern, many folders are missing from the list of retrieved folders.*

Here's your problem: you are assuming there should always be objects with keys ending in `/` to symbolize folders.

This is an incorrect assumption.  They will only be there if you created them, either via the S3 console or the API.  There's no reason to expect them, as S3 doesn't actually need them or use them for anything, and the S3 service does not create them spontaneously, itself.

If you use the API to upload an object with key `foo/bar.txt`, this does not create the `foo/` folder as a distinct object.  It will appear as a folder in the console for convenience, but it isn't there unless at some point you deliberately created it.

Of course, the only way to upload such an object with the console is to "create" the folder unless it already appears -- but *appears in the console* does not necessarily equate to *exists as a distinct object.*

Filtering on `endsWith("/")` is invalid logic.

This is why the underlying API includes `CommonPrefixes` with each ListObjects response if `delimiter` and `prefix` are specified.  This is a list of the next level of "folders", which you have to recursively drill down into in order to find the next level.

> If you specify a prefix, all keys that contain the same string between the prefix and the first occurrence of the delimiter after the prefix are grouped under a single result element called CommonPrefixes. If you don't specify the prefix parameter, the substring starts at the beginning of the key. The keys that are grouped under the CommonPrefixes result element are not returned elsewhere in the response.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

You need to access this functionality with whatever library you or using, or, you need to iterate the entire list of keys and discover the actual common prefixes on `/` boundaries using string splitting.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming a regular hierarchical filesystem consisting of files AND directories. The assumption is correct and S3 is just plain wrong to violate it and give untold amounts of pain to good people who make reasonable assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in case someone faces the same problem in future, the alternative logic I used is as suggested by @Michael above, I iterated through all the keys, splat them at last occurrence of `/`. The first `index` of the returned list +  `/` was the key of a folder, appended it to another list. At the end, returned the `unique` list I was appending into. This gave me all the `folders` and `sub-folders` in a certain prefix location.

**Note that I didn't use `CommonPrefixes` because I wasn't using any `delimiter` and that's because I didn't want the list of `folders` at a certain level but instead `recursively` get all the `folders` and `sub-folders`**

```
def listFoldersRecursively(bucketName: String, fullPath: String): List[String] = {
    try {
      val objects = client.listObjects(bucketName).getObjectSummaries
      val listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
        .withPrefix(fullPath)
        .withBucketName(bucketName)

      val folderPaths = client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest)
        .getObjectSummaries()
        .map(_.getKey)
        .toList

      val foldersList: ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer()
      for (folderPath <- folderPaths) {
        val split = folderPath.splitAt(folderPath.lastIndexOf("/"))
        if (!split._1.equals(""))
          foldersList += split._1 + "/"
      }
      foldersList.toList.distinct
```

**P.S: Catch block is intentionalyy missing due to irrelevancy.**

Answer (score 2):

The `listObjects` function (and others) is paginating, returning up to 100 entries every time.

From the doc:

> Because buckets can contain a virtually unlimited number of keys, the
>   complete results of a list query can be extremely large. To manage
>   large result sets, Amazon S3 uses pagination to split them into
>   multiple responses. Always check the ObjectListing.isTruncated()
>   method to see if the returned listing is complete or if additional
>   calls are needed to get more results. Alternatively, use the
>   AmazonS3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(ObjectListing) method as an easy
>   way to get the next page of object listings.

Comment: If I remove `.filter(_.endsWith("/"))` and check the length of `folderPaths` list, it's 552 (including all the files). I believe that's not the problem. When I use `.filter(_.endsWith("/"))` entries displayed are less than twenty.

Comment: Actually when I don't use `.filter(_.endsWith("/"))`, the list displayed all the keys of files in the folders it's not listing. Normally, it lists folders and files like this:
`folder/
folder/file1
folder/file2`

But it has also some listing like:
`folder/
folder/file1
folder/file2
folder2/file1
folder2/file3`

Now `folder2/file1` is a file in `folder2`, but list doesn't has entry `folder2/`, because of this that `folder2/` isn't listed when I use `.filter(_.endsWith("/"))`. But there's an entry of `folder2/` when I look through some `s3 client` like `dragondisk`.

Comment: `ObjectListing.isTruncated()` also returning `false`.

Comment: The comment above is correct that selecting keys that end with "/" doesn't guarantee you'll get folders. S3 doesn't really support folders, its up to the client to decide how to treat keys with "/" in them. The AWS console does treat these as folders. Anyways, this not related to scala...